# Can I change the mv.db extension of H2 Database arbitrarily?

Tags: database, spring-boot, h2

I'm developing the H2 database in conjunction with SpringBoot is linked SpringBoot.
What I'm curious about is that the file name says, "xxx.mv.db" I'd like to delete the file or change the extension so that it doesn't show any trace of the same database as db". (Of course, I think there will be a problem if I delete it.)
In fact, there is no problem if you run this part in in-memory mode, but due to the structure of development, you have to run it as a file.
Is there such a way?

I tried it in the application.properties file.

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test.aaa

I added "test.aaa" in advance
Failed because the file "test.aaa.mv .db" was eventually created.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what do you want to achieve. Changing the extensions used by H2 is not possible. But renaming the database (the first part of the file name) is possible while the database is closed.

More details from the documentation:

> Database name and location are not stored inside the database files.
>
> While a database is closed, the files can be moved to another directory, and they can be renamed as well (as long as all files of the same database start with the same name and the respective extensions are unchanged).

From: http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html